# Find the derivative dy/dx given some value for x.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I know how to find the derivative of a function by  itself given a function. I can use multiple rules to determine the derivative. However in a situation where I must find the derivative when the x value is equals to some constant, I am tripped up. For example:

Say I have to find the derivative $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ for some function:

$y=\dfrac{1}{x}$

I have found that my derivative is $-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$.

How do I now determine $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ for $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$ when $x = 5$?

**This is using the definition of the derivative!**

Comment: If you gotta use the definition, then just use the definition. Evaluate the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac 1{5+h}-\frac 15}{h}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to just plug $x=5$ back into the thing:

$$\frac d{dx}\frac1x\bigg|_{x=5}=-\frac1{x^2}\bigg|_{x=5}=-\frac1{5^2}$$

The harder way is to use the definition:

$$\frac d{dx}\frac1x\bigg|_{x=5}=\lim_{h\to5}\frac{\frac1h-\frac15}{h-5}=\lim_{h\to5}\frac{\frac{5-h}{5h}}{h-5}=-\lim_{h\to5}\frac1{5h}=-\frac1{5^2}$$

Comment: That is simply beatiful art.

Comment: Referring to me?  :D

Comment: This was very substantive. Great job in explaining, thank you!

Comment: @Donnie :-) No problem and your welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The "multiple rules" you use to find the derivative all follow from the **definition** of the derivative. To use that definition for a particular function $f$ at a particular point, say $x=5$, you must find
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 5} \frac{f(5+h) -f(5)}{h} .
$$

So write that out for the function in your example and do the algebra with fractions to find the limit. Then you can check with the formula you know.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a strange question indeed.

I guess you know how to calculate $f(x)$ when $x=5$ this is $f(5)$.

Then why are you puzzled by plugging $x=5$ into $f'(x)$, this is just $f'(5)$.

$f(x)=\frac1x$ is a function, $g(x)=-\frac1{x^2}$ is also a function and I'm sure you know how to calculate $g(5)$. Well call it $g$ or call it $f'$ there is no difference in evaluating it for some value of the variable.

Now when $y=1/x$ we are just saying that $y(x)$ is a function of $x$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is nothing more than $y'(x)$.

So the definition of $\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg|_{x=5}$ is as usually written $\lim\limits_{h\to 5}\frac{y(h)-y(5)}{h-5}$.

Is it clearer ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.